# Complicated groupby of panda dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two data frames: *df_s_T* and *df_data_T* and want to aggregate (for example with mean aggregation function) the second one based on the first one in a column-wise manner. Here is what I mean by example:

```
ind = ['d1','d2','d3','d4']
my_data_ints = {'s1': [1, 2, 1, 2], 's2': [1, 2, 1, 1],'s3': [1, 1, 1, 1]}
df_s_T = pd.DataFrame(data=my_data_ints, index = ind).T
my_data = {'s1': [-1, 2, 5, 12], 's2': [-2, 2, 4, 10.5], 's3': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
df_data_T = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index = ind).T
```

which can be visualized like this:

```
print df_data_T
print df_s_T
     d1   d2   d3    d4
s1 -1.0  2.0  5.0  12.0
s2 -2.0  2.0  4.0  10.5
s3  1.0  2.0  3.0   4.0
    d1  d2  d3  d4
s1   1   2   1   2
s2   1   2   1   1
s3   1   1   1   1
```

Desired output (calculating mean for each column for all rows with equal values):

```
     d1   d2   d3     d4                    
1  -0.66  2.0  4.0   7.25
2   nan   2.0  nan  12.00
```

In my example for *d1* and *d3* columns the value of row 2 in the desired output dataframe is nan because there are no values "2" in the columns *d1* and *d3* in the *df_s_T* dataframe.

What I've accomplished succesfully is aggregation by a fixed column (for example the last one), see below

```
df_data_T_new = df_data_T.groupby(df_s_T.iloc[:,-1]).mean()
df_data_T_new
     d1   d2   d3     d4
d4                      
1  -0.5  2.0  3.5   7.25
2  -1.0  2.0  5.0  12.00
```

I want to create a smart solution possibly without writing loops. It should somehow first get all possible values in *df_data_T* in order for the resulting data frame to be correctly build.

Thanks in advance for the propositions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe think of using `zip` and `concat` the the result back

```
pd.concat([df1[x].groupby(df2[y]).mean() for x , y in zip(df1,df2)],axis=1)
Out[44]: 
          d1   d2   d3     d4
d4                           
1  -0.666667  2.0  4.0   7.25
2        NaN  2.0  NaN  12.00
```